# Syntax error on else

Tags: java

Got probably a simple problem but where ever I google it it seems the problem
 is a semicolon at the end of the if statement, the problem is eclipse giving me the syntax error asking to delete my else on the else  if statement, this happens nearly all the time for me and i end up using multiple IF's.

```
        if(saleStatus == false || offerPrice <= currentOffer)
        {
            System.out.print("Error, sale is not open");
            return false;
        }

        else if(currentOffer >= reservePrice)
        {
            saleStatus = false;
        }
```

Comment: please provide full code

Comment: Its right, you dont need else in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Every path your function can take **must** return a value, if you specify that it will return something.

In this case, you have probably specified it as

```
access_modifier boolean function_name(params){
...             // ^return type 

}
```

So, all code paths must return a boolean.
**In your code,** if it takes the `else...` path, and exits without returning anything, that isn't permitted.

```
  else if(currentOffer >= reservePrice)
        {
            saleStatus = false;
            //return something here (null if you don't care)
        }
//or return something here (which all code-paths hit)
```

If you use an IDE like **[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)**, it can warn you in advance about things like this.

Comment: It is permitted. You can skip the return statement in the else block, assuming you have a return statement after the if and elses. .

Comment: @Mob I have mentioned that. It is just that all code-paths must return a value.

Comment: @Cthulhu - +1 it seems you are analyzing with perception.

Comment: @nathan Well, there is nothing else wrong with the code you have posted. I'd say the error is elsewhere. Post more code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `return` statement in your `else` block. If a return type is declared in your method, the method would not know what to return if the code enters the else block.

Put one in it or after (*).

Answer (score 0):

In the first if, you return a value, so there is no point on specifying "else" because the rest of the method is not executed.

Some developers avoid multiple return statements in functions for code quality.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your code in a class declaration, with minimum additional declarations, and a return after the whole if-else structure, and Eclipse shows no errors. I suggest writing a similarly minimal complete program that does show the problem, and posting it.

You do not need "else if" rather than "if" for the second test, but it should be harmless.

```
  public class Bad {
    boolean saleStatus;
    int offerPrice;
    int currentOffer;
    int reservePrice;

    public  boolean problem() {
      if(saleStatus == false || offerPrice <= currentOffer)
      {
          System.out.print("Error, sale is not open");
          return false;
      }

      else if(currentOffer >= reservePrice)
      {
          saleStatus = false;
      }
      return true;
    } 
  }
```